# Component is rendered before clicking on button in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am new to Reactjs . I am making a todo app using it . So in developing phase I want the Delete Button to console.log() the "hello" onClick. But whenever I submit a new todo task , even without click the delete button it console.log() the "hello" and if then I click Delete Button nothing happens on console.
I can't understand where's the problem . I surfed the internet but nothing worked.

May anyone tell where's the problem ?

Here's my code :

```
import './styles/App.css';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Form, Button, ListGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';
import DropDown from './components/DropDowns';
import DeleteButton from './components/DeleteButton';
function App() {
  const [todoList, setTodo] = useState([]);
  const [Ttitle, setTitle] = useState('');
  const [desc, setDesc] = useState('No Description');
  return (
    <div className="App d-flex flex-column">
      <h1 className="mt-3">Your ToDo App</h1>
      <div className="container-fluid mx-0 px-0">
        <div className="Todo__Res mx-5">
          <h2>Your ToDo List</h2>
          <div className="List">
            <ul className="Todo__List">
              {todoList ? todoList.map((item, index) => <li key={index}>
                <ListGroup>
                  <ListGroup.Item>{item.title}<DropDown desc={item.desc} /><DeleteButton index={index}/></ListGroup.Item>
                </ListGroup>
              </li>) : 0}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="Todo__Add mx-5">
          <h2>Add Your ToDo</h2>
          <Form>
            <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlInput1">
              <Form.Label>Title</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Take Jack to School..." onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)} />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1">
              <Form.Label>Description</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control as="textarea" rows={3} placeholder="Buy him a cake..." onChange={e => setDesc(e.target.value)} onDefault={desc} />
            </Form.Group>
            <Button variant="primary" type="submit" onClick={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              const kk = {
                title: Ttitle,
                desc: desc
              }
              setTodo([...todoList, kk]);
            }}>
              Submit
            </Button>
          </Form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

//Delete Button Component :
import {Button}from 'react-bootstrap'
export default function DeleteButton({index}){
return(
    <>
    <Button variant="outline-danger" onClick={console.log("hello")}>Delete</Button>
    </>
);
}
```

Thanking You ,

Yours Truly

Rishabh Raghwendra

Comment: you should pass a function to onClick, it should be `() => console.log('hello')`

Comment: if you write like that, `console.log('hello')` is automatically execute whenever component render(re-render). You should pass a function to that: `() => console.log('hello')`

Comment: @nmDat . Thanks alot bro..‍♀️

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function immediately on render. you should just pass a function to be executed on click

Here you go, this should fix your code issue,

```
<Button variant="outline-danger" onClick={() => console.log("hello")}>Delete</Button>
```